# Toolbar in coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

How can i do like on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enWVNP3Gifg) video?

This video is demonstrating of this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/scrolling-techniques-for-material-design--cms-24435)
, but i doesnt work.

[Source code of example activity.](https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-MaterialDesign-ScrollingTechniques/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_technique2.xml)

Full source code: [Github](https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-MaterialDesign-ScrollingTechniques)

Answer (score 0):

This question is most probably duplicated but here is the Google Material Design link for you, follow this instructions.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

https://material.google.com/components/toolbars.html

Comment: How this links can help me? I wrote this articles many times. My problem is that i cant realise  described design

Comment: You can use Coordinator Layout and Toolbar for making your application like what you want. In these links you can find how to make it.

Comment: i know it. But i dont know how i can do exactly  this situation.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enWVNP3Gifg

Comment: did you try to hide toolbar with animation manually when view triggered scroll event? 

  mToolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));

Comment: i think it is not a true way. I hope this situation may be made with the layout_scrollFlags. Thats why i posted my question :(